# Email verification in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am new with grails and am developing a web application in grails.

In my registration page I am getting the user's email id and I need to send a mail with authentication link.

http://grails.org/plugin/mail

http://grails.org/plugin/email-confirmation

I have referred these pages and many other pages to do this task.
 But the problem is, my email is not sending.

I have used

```
Gmail SMTP server address : smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP username : myid@gmail.com
Gmail SMTP password : -my password-
Gmail SMTP port : 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required : yes
```

Mail settings are:

```
grails { 
    mail { 
        host = "smtp.gmail.com" 
        port = 465 
        username = "myId@gmail.com" 
        password = "mypassword" 
        props = [
            "mail.smtp.auth":"true", 
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465", 
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class": "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"] 
    } 
} 
grails.mail.default.from="noreply@gmail.com"
```

but at least

```
sendMail {     
  to "friend@gmail.com"     
  subject "Hello "     
  body 'How are you?' 
}
```

is not working.

The exception occured is

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /MailVerificationDemo/user/signup/form
Class
    java.net.ConnectException
Message
    Connection refused

Around line 104 of MailMessageBuilder.groovy

101:            log.trace("Sending mail ${getDescription(message)}} ...")102:        }103:104:        mailSender.send(message instanceof MimeMailMessage ? message.mimeMessage : message)105:106:        if (log.traceEnabled) {107:            log.trace("Sent mail ${getDescription(message)}} ...")

Around line 41 of grails-app/services/grails/plugin/mail/MailService.groovy

38:        callable.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST39:        callable.call()40:41:        messageBuilder.sendMessage()42:    }43:44:    def getMailConfig() {

Around line 18 of grails-app/controllers/user/UserController.groovy

15:            return16:        }17:18:        mailService.sendMail {19:            to userInstance.email20:            subject "New User Confirmation"21:            html g.render(template:"mailtemplate",model:[code:userInstance.confirmCode])

Around line 195 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java

192:            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {193:             log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",194:                     new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });195:               chain.doFilter(request, response);196:              return;197:         }198:

Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java

60:     try {61:            // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping62:         if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {63:                doFilter(request, response, chain);64:          }65:            else {66:               chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

[image: this is the exception]

Comment: Paste your mail settings from config.groovy.

Are you getting any errors ? What happens, do you see any thing on console !

Comment: grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "myId@gmail.com"
        password = "mypassword"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}

grails.mail.default.from="noreply@gmail.com"

the view page is not changing.

Comment: can you login into `Gmail` with those credentials? `Gmail` often refuses connections the first time from an unknown client. Look for email notifications for this in your inbox. also check https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257?p=client_login&rd=1

Comment: I have tried all these....
But still the same error.

Comment: as the trace suggests ssl is used and so your config is most likely picked up.  can you test connecting? e.g. ``telnet smtp.gmail.com 465``?

Comment: bash: telnet: command not found is the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this it's worked for me.
Notice that: `Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required : yes.`
But you don't put `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true"`

```
grails.mail.host="smtp.gmail.com"
grails.mail.port=587
grails.mail.username="yourUsernameHere"
grails.mail.password="yourPwdHere"
grails.mail.from="defaultMailFromHere"
grails.mail.props = ['mail.smtp.auth': "true",
        "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true",
        "mail.from":"defaultMailFromHere"]
grails.mail.javaMailProperties = ['mail.smtp.auth': "true",
        "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true",
        "mail.from":"defaultMailFromHere"]
```